# How to prompt messagebox once inside a for loop in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

Is it possible to display a single messagebox inside a for loop codes?

I am trying to but cannot successfully make it.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean a single inside a loop ? A singla that will update through the loop ? (not possible) or a different one for each iterations ? (possible)

Comment: If you are "trying but cannot successfully make it", you should be able to [edit] your question and provide at least one effort you've made. "I tried, but it doesn't work" without posting an attempt is like telling your teacher "I did my homework, but my dog ate it so I can't turn it in". Questions asking for code here should show at least a reasonable amount of effort solving the problem yourself. StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @phadaphunk..Sir a single messagebox that will prompt inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Code inside a loop, by definition, is meant to execute multiple times, for each iteration of it, so if you don't want to have multiple messages, move that call *outside* of the loop so it executes only once. This would be the main way of doing so, because it makes it clear that there will be ever only one of them.

Otherwise, you can condition its display, by some particular condition that's warranted to happen only once, possibly caching the result from the user. The second snippet from *phadaphunk* does something like that.

Comment: Still got a -1 for it. Still don't understand why. Maybe my Vb syntax is a little rusty.

Comment: Maybe it's not copy-paste ready? It's not crazy at all anyway, describes the idea even if there might be a little syntax typo, who nows why?

Answer (score -1):

From you question, I get that you don't understand how it works below.
The loop is a set of instructions that must be executed "x" number of time. So everything that is in the body of that loop will be executed that number of time. Which means that if there are 5 iterations to the loop, you will get 5 messagebox.

This is how you do it if you want a different box for each iterations :

```
For Each x As Integer In someList
    MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
```

Otherwise you can't do it unless there is a certain condition that explains to the compiler at which iteration you want the message box to appear. Something like

```
For Each x As Integer In someList
    If (x == 5)
    MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
```